# mean square convergence vs almost sure convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, random

I saw a few examples that show that almost sure convergence doesn't imply convergence in mean square. Can anyone find an example of a random series that converges in mean square but doesn't converge almost surely?

Comment: Can you clarify the requirement of being *random*? Do you want the summands to be independent random variables, for example?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. Random series is a series that depends on a random variable/vector. For example, x[n]=b/n, where b is uniformly distributed on [0,1]. If any other assumptions are required for the sake of the example, then sure - assume independence

Answer (score -1):

Look at

X[n,w]=exp(-n^2*(w-1/n)) where w is in [0,1] (set of all out comes) and n is the time index.

Only for w=0 it does not converge so it almost surely converges (prob 1). But when it does not converge (i.e. w=0) the sequence goes to infinity exponentially fast making it not converging in mean square sense.

Comment: it's an example from
Probability Random Processes and Estimation Theory for Engineers
John Woods; Henry Stark

Published by Prentice Hall PTR

ISBN 10: 013711706X ISBN 13: 9780137117062